# JQuery Ajax and Posting multiple complex objects to asp.net MVC Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

`Greetings,

Having problem posting multiple parameters to an mc controller method.

```
controller...
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSomething(SomeDomainObject domainObject, bool anOption)
{
}

Ajax Code...
function performPostData(postDataOptions,closeWindow) {
        $.ajax({ type: postDataOptions.httpVerb,
            url: postDataOptions.url,
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: postDataOptions.data(),
            success: function () {
                if (closeWindow) {
                    var window = $('#window').data("kendoWindow");
                    window.close();             
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                var validator = $("#editBase").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator"),
                status = $(".editValidationStatus");
                var err = msg.Message;
                status.text(err).addClass("invalid");
            }
        });
    }

JScript function to format data...

function GetPostData()
{
    var _domainObject={            
            prop1: 1,
            prop2: 2,
            prop3: 3                      
        };
        return JSON.stringify({ domainObject:_domainObject,anOption: true});
}
```

I seeing in network capture that this is the request body:

```
{"domainObject":{"prop1":1,"prop2":2,"Prop3":3},"anOption":true}
```

The controller raises the following exception:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'anOption' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SaveSomething(Domain.Data.SomeDomainObject, Boolean)' in 'Reports.Controllers.TestController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters
```

I have been spinning my wheels for hours trying to get a simple domain object and another parameter of type bool to be serialized and passed to my controller. Any ideas?

Comment: The next thing I tried is to create a SaveObjectRequestObject like SaveObjectRequest:DomainObject{ public bool AnOption{get;set;}}. This actually traced through to the controller but my base object properties are never set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the content type parameter in the jquery ajax call.
You should explicitly set it as json, as in this piece of code:

```
function performPostData(postDataOptions,closeWindow) {
    $.ajax({ type: postDataOptions.httpVerb,
        url: postDataOptions.url,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        ...rest of your code
```

Otherwise it will get its default value (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Comment: It turns out that after I flattened the controller request obejct out I could trace to the controller. Then removing the return JSON.stringify({ request: SaveDomainObjectRequest}); and only returning someDomainObjectRequest worked. I will mark your response as an answer, however, I do not have the luxury of time to revert back and test :(

Comment: This answer fixed my issues. For some reason the jQuery defaults aren't good enough for my MVC controller to bind complex collections. Simply sending the JSON variant (as described in this post) made everything bind perfectly.  Many thanks!!